# Debug C# DLL generated by CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile using VS Express

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-express

I have a C# Windows Form myApp.exe program that at run time can compile another C# file, helloWorld, and execute it using reflection method.  I use the .NET CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile method in myApp to compile helloWorld into helloWorld.dll.

Is there a way I can debug the helloWorld.cs/dll (set breakpoint, singlestepping) using VS Express.  If not, is there a way I can debug (singlestepping or thru setting breakpoint) helloWorld within myApp.exe using some defined .NET methods?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you provide how you call `CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile `?

Comment: I have: parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
                    parameters.GenerateInMemory = false;
                    parameters.IncludeDebugInformation = true;

Answer (score 2):

you can set

```
parameters.IncludeDebugInformation = true;
parameters.CompilerOptions += " /debug:pdbonly";
```

where `parameters is CompilerParameters`
then you can debug normally

Comment: I have a few questions.  Can I debug this using Visual Studio Express?  How do I setup VS Express to detect myApp?  Don't I need to create a VS project in order to debug it in VS Express?  If so do I create a VS project for myApp or helloWorld?  Thanks.

Comment: if you have vs project then you can run it with debug and breakpoints, also you can try attach to process myapp.exe

Comment: Attach to a process only works with VS standard/professional.  I don't think it work with VS Express.  I could be wrong.